# How to convert 'users' in accessRules from Yii1 into behaviors() in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, behavior, yii2

I have these codes in my Controller.php when in Yii:

```
public function filters()
{
    return array('accessControl');
}

public function accessRules()
{
    $allAuthUsers = MyAdmin::model()->getAllUsers(); 

    if (empty($allAuthUsers))
        $allUsers = array(NULL);

    return array(
        array('allow',
            'users' => $allAuthUsers, 
        ),
        array('deny'),
    );
}
```

But, how can I implement this into Yii2 using **behaviors()** ?

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,                        
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

I wanted to put an array list of certain users which is allow to login to the system.

May someone advise how can I do the similar way in Yii2 as how I did in Yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea cannot work, you only allow certain users to login, but you do not know what user tries to login until they do. So what you are trying to accomplish cannot work like you want it to because it does not make sense.

What you did in yii1 is to allow access to a controller (not login) to certain users. Your code still does not make sense (but it works) because you actually allow everybody to have access anyway.
So your exact code can be written in yii2

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['logout', 'register', 'register-interest', 'forgot-password', 'login-register', 'reset-password', 'auth_login', 'auth_register', 'request-password-reset'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['register', 'auth_login', 'auth_register', 'register-interest', 'login-register', 'forgot-password', 'reset-password', 'request-password-reset'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Why do you insist to make use a list of users instead of using roles? Here is the official RBAC documentation https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-authorization.md . The idea is allow only a specific role (or roles) to access the controller, after a user logs in assign the role to him based a criteria. You can create very complex roles but if you do not want to you can create simple ones too.

Also you can take a look at this: https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user with the documentation here: http://yii2-user.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html for inspiration on what you want to do. It actually has something similar to what you want too, it has a list of usernames that will be admins.

Comment: you are right, I wanted only that 'list of admin users' allowed to certain Controller(actually all controller) after logged in. You are right as everyone can logged in as long as they have my own openid username and password. I using OpenID for login module. So, how can I makes my codes make sense?

Comment: there is no $users property in yii\filters\AccessRule.

Comment: Sorry I did not realize that there is no users in yii2. I use roles as it is normal.

Answer (score 3):

Use this function:

```
       array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','delete','update','approve','unapprove','admin'),
            'expression'=>'YourFunc(UserRole::LEVEL_ADMIN)',
        ),
```

and in `YourFunc()`, return true or false

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this. It works but I am not sure if my idea/concept is correct.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'ruleConfig' => [
                'class' => 'app\modules\mymodules\components\MyAccessRule'
            ],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,  
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Then, in my MyAccessRule.php:

```
protected function matchRole($user)
{
    if( !empty($user->identity->username) && (MyAdmin::isAdmin($user->identity->username) )
    {

        return true;            

    }       

    return false;

}
```

@Mihai P., could you please advise? Anyone could kindly advise too. Thanks. :)

Comment: I edited my response, just learn to use the RBAC option either with a simple PHP file or with a database. It is powerful and easy to use after you figure it out. You will never go back afterwards.

Comment: Use the php version to start with, you can move it to the DB easily later.